# TS : Create a generic assert type function

Tags: typescript

Is it possible de create a genric assert type function for object.

Something like this :

```
assertIsTypeOf<ExpectedType extends object>(obj: unknown): obj is ExpectedType {
    return Object.keys(obj).every((key) => key in (keyof ExpectedType));
}
```

Do you have an idea how to do something like that ? Or a better way ?

Comment: How it should work in your mind?

Comment: Functions with type predicates can be generic. But you *can not* use the generic type during runtime to do any validation. You would have to pass an extra parameter for doing the validation as you would do in JavaScript, see [here](https://tsplay.dev/NB5Ozw) on how that could look like. Would this answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, functions with type predicates can be generic. But since types are erased during compilation, you can *not* use types at runtime to do any kind of validation. So you have to supply additional arguments to do the validation at runtime.

You could possibly send another object containing all the properties you want to check.

```
function assertIsTypeOf<T extends object>(obj: unknown, expectedType: T): obj is T {
    return !!obj && Object.keys(expectedType).every((key) => key in obj);
}

console.log(assertIsTypeOf({ a: "123" }, { a: "" }))
console.log(assertIsTypeOf({}, { a: "" }))
```

Based on your implementation it does not look like you are actually checking the type of the properties. You only check *if they exist*. So you could also just pass an array of property names.

```
function assertIsTypeOf<T extends string>(
  obj: unknown, 
  expectedProps: T[]
): obj is Record<T, unknown> {
    return !!obj && expectedProps.every((key) => key in obj);
}

console.log(assertIsTypeOf({ a: "123" }, ["a"]))
console.log(assertIsTypeOf({}, ["a"]))
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDBmFcDsGMBcEsD2kAEBDAzhgpgJ1gJIYAqAngA7YDyoAPMStgB6zaQAmGKGsu8kAcwB8ACkQAjAFYAuFFADWkRAHdIAGkZNKcbOwAKuROQyziAbQC6ASlkTJKeFwBK2aIlzt6GhUtVCUAN7AKCEouNiw4LioAIQxdigAZIma2qz6hsYAdNgAbnikIiLy2KRWKAC8-iWkDqh2VgDcwAC+IG6QGIgANthZ3YgCIpg4+ERklDQiAeiyAEQAjABMAMxzKC0aZnNoc9ZWwB1dvf2Dw1h4hCQU1KDTmyjbu-tAA)